# SQLAlchemy: Create tables from existing classes using a different engine

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I already have an engine defined for my postgres database. I want to create a new engine using sqlite and use what existing classes I already have.

I have it set up like this for postgres:

```
conn_url = '<connection_string>'
engine = create_engine(conn_url, echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()


class SomeTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    some_field = Column(String(100))
```

How do I use `SomeTable` with an sqlite engine like this `engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was

```
import SomeTable from models

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
SomeTable.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I thought I'd have to do that for every model that I have, but it works just fine using any model.